# Search and Replace ( multiple lines )

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, replace

**Hello StackOverflow Community!**

I'm working on a **bash** script to change in **Dynamic** text file, I want to replace multiple lines with one line.

Ex:

This example, I want to replace **THIS**

```
CCCCC 
DDDDD
```

With `KKKKK`

Before script

```
AAAAA
CCCCC
DDDDD
BBBBB
CCCCC
DDDDD
CCCCC
```

After script

```
AAAAA
KKKKK
BBBBB
KKKKK
CCCCC
```

I found a script to replace using ( `sed` ) but it doesn't replace multiple lines.

NOTE: I'm a beginner at scripting so please explain how it can be done easy :)

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sed expression you are looking for is something like this:

```
sed -e '/CCCCC/{N;s/CCCCC\nDDDDD/KKKKK/}'
```

What does this do?

It commands `sed` to execute the command block delimited by braces whenever there is a match to the regex `CCCCC` (you may prefer to substitute this by `^CCCCC$`)

Whenever the aforementioned block is executed, the first thing it does is add the next line to the pattern space. And then it just performs a substitution command.

See also [the answers to this question in the UNIX & Linux StackExchange community](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26284/how-can-i-use-sed-to-replace-a-multi-line-string).

**Please note** more `N;` command to add more line to the pattern space.

Ex:

```
sed -e '/CCCCC/{N; N; s/CCCCC\nDDDDD\nBBBBB/KKKKK/}'
```

Comment: What do you mean by "on more than two lines"?

Comment: if I did `sed -e '/CCCCC/{N;s/CCCCC\nDDDDD\nBBBBB/KKKKK/}'` will it work?

Comment: That will substitute a `CCCCC` line followed by a `DDDDD`, followed by a `BBBBB` line to `KKKKK`. If that's what you want, then yes, it will do it.

Comment: Yes, but When I try it with two lines it works, but more than two ( Three or more  ) it doesn't.

Comment: Yes, you are right, my fault. You must add the third line to the pattern space: `sed -e '/CCCCC/{N; N; s/CCCCC\nDDDDD\nBBBBB/KKKKK/}'`. Please note the extra `N` command to add the third line to the pattern space.

Comment: thanks :) it works but applies only once, I need to change a very big dynamic file. even after adding ( g ) for the global

Comment: Can you provide an exact example of what you have already tried, what you have got, and what you expected? I have tried the aforementioned `sed` command, and it worked for a whole file with three occurrences (one of them overlaping with a previous `CCCCC` match), but it was not a _dynamic_ one.

Comment: Sorry my fault, I was trying on a **dynamic** text I needed to change some patterns

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
tr '\n' ' ' < yourText.txt | sed "s/CCCCC DDDDD/KKKKK/g" | tr -s ' ' '\n'
```

To save it, simply add `> another.txt` at the end of the above command

Comment: Please don't punish answerers for trying to answer the question, even when the question is considered unwarranted by few people. We went great length to produce answers.

Comment: It's just @jww up to his usual tricks. I'll upvote everyone to compensate, as usual...

Comment: Thanks, it's good but it will give a problem if there are spaces in the Text, phrases etc..
Also, it didn't work with multiple lines, works only with two lines.

Comment: This answer is provided specifically for the pattern you specified to be replaced in your question. If you want anything more complicated than this, perl or python are much better candidates for your script. Take a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26284/how-can-i-use-sed-to-replace-a-multi-line-string?newreg=803060fd449c4a74b432ace0085cdf04

Comment: When you already made sure your file is without windows line endings, you can use `\r` as a temporary field: `tr '\n' '\r' < yourText.txt | sed 's/CCCCC\rDDDDD/KKKKK/g' | tr -s '\r' '\n'`